# Spring Boot cache read and scheduled evict same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am currently developing an application that uses `Spring Cache`.

Currently it's schedually evicted in every 5 mins, but it's really high traffical application and it's possible that while deleting the cache any user can read the cache in same time.

I could call cacheable method inside the eviction method but are there any better practices for that behavior.